# Get Branch name in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my Gitlab CI, I have a stage that triggers another stage by api call trigger and  I want to pass the current branch name as parameter to the other project holding the trigger. I used the `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` for this, it seemed to work, but now that I call the stage only when merging the branch to master, the `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` always says "master".

In the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables) it says "The branch or tag name for which project is built", do I understand it correctly that it kind of holds the target branch of my working branch?

I tried to get the current branch in gitlab ci with `git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed 's!refs\/heads\/!!'` as well but it was empty.

Is `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` the variable I am looking for and something is going wrong or do I need something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this also may be useful to know https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/32784

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by “a stage that triggers another stage by api call trigger”. But, generally speaking, GitLab CI jobs are part of a CI pipeline, and CI pipelines are created for a branch or tag.

The `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` variable contains the name of the branch or tag that the pipeline was created for.

The `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` is "The target branch name of the merge request."

from [GitLab Predefined Variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

Comment: [Full list of predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

Comment: `echo ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}` was the right one for me.

Answer (score 16):

Note that a rule like the following that checks the value of `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` (intended to prevent running this step when a PR has been merged into `master` branch) will not work as expected:

```yaml
build-python-c4d:
  stage: pre
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
```

From [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`:

> The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.

Instead you should use:

```
build-python-c4d:
  stage: pre
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master")
```